# How to store output of recv()?

Tags: c, sockets, dynamic, recv

In C I had working code but have no idea why it worked, so I started rewriting it so I could actually understand what is going on.

So far so good! I rewrote and am 90% sure I understand everything that is going on now; the issue however, is that I have no idea how to store the data chunk received by `recv` (`databff`) into my pre-allocated buffer (`htmlbff`).

Consider the following code (note that I stripped this down quite a bit, so it only includes the basics, e.g. no memory reallocation or leak protection, etc...):

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 4096
#define MAXDATASIZE 256

char *htmlbff, databff[MAXDATASIZE];
int c, i = BUFFERSIZE, q = 0;          
if(!(htmlbff = malloc(i)))
{
    printf("\nError! Memory allocation failed!");
    return 0x00;
}
while((c = recv(sock, databff, MAXDATASIZE, 0)) > 0)
{
     /*memory checks stripped out since they are irrelevent for this post*/
     /*store data to the appropriate area in htmlbff*/
     q += c;           
}
```

So (if I am doing this right, and things are going as I think they are) `c` is the size of the current data chunk, and `q` is the total amount of data received so far (`q` is incremented by `c` each time the loop repeats). At the moment I am using `q` for memory handling (in case anybody was wondering) but I believe that it will also have purpose in the solution to this problem.

At any rate the question I am asking is in regards to the second comment. How do I store the data from recv into `htmlbff` correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `memcpy`, and offset `htmlbff` by `q`:

```
memcpy(htmlbff + q, databff, c);
```

You can similarly `recv` directly into `htmlbff`:

```
c = recv(sock, htmlbff + q, MAXDATASIZE, 0));
```

But it's fine to keep a separate buffer, and depending upon your full code, it may make things clearer.

Be sure that you add checks against `BUFFERSIZE` so that you don't copy past the bounds of `htmlbff`. You mentioned that you've stripped out `realloc` handling, so maybe you're already handling this.

Your constant names are a bit confusing, when buffering data I would use `BUFFERSIZE` to indicate the size of each *chunk*, i.e. the size of `databff`.

Comment: I really like this answer thank you. I found this one most useful because I can now just skip using the buffer and write directly into htmlbff.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`memcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) to copy (append) data to the `htmlbff` but you also need to ensure you do not exceed the size of `htmlbff`. Either stop receving data when `BUFFERSIZE` bytes have been received or use [`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) to extend `htmlbff` to contain more data.

For example:

```
char* htmlbff;
size_t htmlbff_size = BUFFERSIZE;
htmlbff = malloc(htmlbff_size);

if (htmlbff)
{
    while((c = recv(sock, databff, MAXDATASIZE, 0)) > 0)
    {
        if (c + q > htmlbff_size)
        {
            htmlbff_size *= 2; /* Arbitrary doubling of size. */
            char* tmp = realloc(htmlbff, htmlbff_size);
            if (tmp)
            {
                htmlbff = tmp;
            }
            else
            {
                /* memory allocation failure. */
                free(htmlbff);
                htmlbff = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        memcpy(htmlbff + q, databff, c);
        q += c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you, and that's exactly how I'm managing my memory already, except that I've added another step to just realloc the size of the buffer to exactly how many bytes I need when finished looping. Again thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is `recv()` data directly into `htmlbff`, unless you need to do more processing on it.

Make sure that you `realloc()` `htmlbff` when `i - q` is less than `MAXDATASIZE` so that there is always room for another `recv()`.

Then you would call `recv(sock, htmlbff + q, MAXDATASIZE, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep reallocating/expanding the buffer to fit all the data (if the data read off the socket exceeds MAXDATASIZE) = That way as recv reads data into the databff, your htmlbff can grow in memory and then the new read can be appended to your overall htmlbff.

q and c are like cursors to keep track of where you are up to and how far you have to go.

```
memcpy(htmlbff+q, databff, c); //Do this in your whle loop to append the data
```